# Iterate over array and use elements as data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

How do I loop through an array and add the elements of the array to the data attribute of the spans inside a div?

**html**

```
<div id="wordBank">
    <span>Play</span>
    <span>Game</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var words = ["play", "game"];

$.each(words, function(index, value){
    $("#wordBank span").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('data-word', value);
    });
});
```

**Current output**

```
<div id="wordBank">
    <span data-word="game">Play</span>
    <span data-word="game">Game</span>
</div>
```

**Desired output**

```
<div id="wordBank">
    <span data-word="play">Play</span>
    <span data-word="game">Game</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need nested loops. Try to iterate the spans and look up the word by index like `words[spanIndex]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to loop on single array and access the value on corresponding index. You don't need a nested loop here.

```js
var words = ["play", "game"];


$("#wordBank span").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('data-word', words[index]);
});
  
console.log(document.querySelector('#wordBank').outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wordBank">
    <span>Play</span>
    <span>Game</span>
</div>
```